# I cant find "android " among the preferences like general, ant, help, etc

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an issue with my eclipse communicating with the android sdk.

I have installed all I need to but when I go to preferences in Eclipse, I can't see "Android" among the list of preferences (e.g general, ant, help etc).

Please what do I do? I really need to start developing apps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's installed properly, and that you have restarted after the install. Go to `Help -> About Eclipse` and push the `Installation Details` button and see if it's listed in the installed software. If not, install it.